# Can i use phpmyadmin's import.php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, windows, phpmyadmin

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370112/sql-aggregates-with-php) report to an "old" question i asked to you (Today ^^).
But you don't find any answers to help me (no, don't cry [image]).
I'm not going to re-ask the same question, we will focus on this:
[image]
So i tryed to make a testImport.php file with this very rich content :

```
<?php
    include '../../apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/import.php';
?>
```

But it return me this (hope it's not too small) :
[image]

My question is : Can i use this external php file to do what i asked in [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370112/sql-aggregates-with-php) ?
If yes how ?

Thanks for all.

---

EDIT :
What i don't understand is "C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\common.inc.php" really exist, i searched it and found it :/

---

Comment: Simplest solution would be to add the PMA location to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you explain with details please because i don't understand, you wan't me to edit the path of my windows (server) and add a php file to it ? (Curious)

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: I don't understand why you want me to add a folder in my path. The file "import.php is found and logically it's used to find it's "friends" (the other php files like Error-Handler.class.php). So how can it help me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to directly use import.php, without modifying it. The reason is that all of these scripts are looking for a token, this is a protection mechanism inside phpMyAdmin. Calling the script directly will send you back to phpMyAdmin's login page.